# Binding magic methods seemingly no longer works in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to bind an instance method which happens to also be a magic method, however python3 doesn't seem to be able to recognize this binding when I try to(indirectly) call the magic method.

This method of patching magic functions used to work in python 2, but no more in python 3.

The code looks something like this:

```py
class Test: 
    def __init__(self, x): 
        self._x = x 
        self.calc_hash = self._x.__hash__ 
        self.__hash__ = self._x.__hash__

t = Test(5)
print(hash(5))
print(t.calc_hash())  # prints the same as hash(5)
print(hash(t))  # prints a value different from that of hash(5)
```

I expected python 3 would work here just as python 2 did, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: This hasn't worked in any reasonable 2.x code for quite a while... `__methods__` are always done on the type, not the instance for new style classes... using `class Test` in Python 2.x would have created an old style class (as opposed to `class Test(object)` ) but old-style classes are gone in 3.x.

Comment: @JonClements OK. So I understand it doesn't work with new-style classes in all python versions. So is the only way to write the same code now to define __hash__ as a full instance method inside `Test` class?

Comment: Yeah... looks like you probably want to re-write as `def __hash__(self): return hash(self._x)`...

Comment: There're times when I miss some possibilities that once existed in python 2. :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's explained in the data model page in python documentation, albeit buried deep inside the page. This's the section that explains the lookup mechanism for special methods. https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup

The bottom line is: special method lookups are performed on class types, not against instance dictionaries.